# browserstack error : Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I am facing issues running automation test over browser stack. I get the following error:

> : Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies
>   are disabled inside 'data:' URLs. (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763

My automation runs fine one local. What could be causing this issue on browserstack.

Comment: Looks like generic Chrome issue [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=728).  You would want to verify that the versions of your local **Selenium webdriver--Selenium standalone server--Browser version** are same as that of the BrowserStack's versions.

Comment: @SanketParlikar Question updated. please see if you got any clue.

Comment: still that doesn't help much. You will have to check the versions of your local setup and BrowserStack components. If its same then you need to get back to BrowserStack. But from the looks of it, you should check google's link which has similar issues.